# How to populate dynamic input field with dynamic select option in jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am trying to populate input field with the value of selected option both are dynamically loaded. I am able to load selected option value and can update it when option changed. but if there are 10 input field and 10 select option tags and i select one option from 10 tags than all 10 input fields show same value. Every input field have 10 options. I need to change value individually .

here is function of jquery,

```
$("#myselect").change(function () {
    $( "select option:selected" ).each(function() {
        $('.returnValue').val($( this ).text());
    });
});
```

I want to insert individual product quantity in input field.

I am struggling for two days please help.

```
<select id="myselect">
    <option value="1">1</option>
    <option value="2">2</option>
    <option value="3">3</option>
    <option value="4">4</option>
</select>

<input class="returnValue" type="text" value="">
```

Comment: your selector says that all inputs with the `returnValue` class will get assigned, so therefore, the last iteration of your inner loop would set all inputs to the last value of `$(this).text()`

Comment: You want to make sum of all the products' quantity selected from all select box? For eg. from select - 1 selected '3' and from select - 2 selected '4' then input field will have value 7 and so on...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can solve your problem in different ways:

If the select and input fields are one after another you may use:

```
$(this).next('.returnValue').val($( this ).val());
```

Another approach can be based on adding for each select a new attribute like:

```
input-field="newlass1"
```

And so add a new class to the corresponding input field in a way to link the select and input field.

In this case you can do it:

```
$('input.' + $(this).attr('input-field')).val($( this ).val());
```

The snippet:

```js
$("[id^=myselect]").change(function () {
  
  
  //$(this).next('.returnValue').val($( this ).val());
  
  
  $('input.' + $(this).attr('input-field')).val($( this ).val());
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.0/jquery.min.js"></script>


<select id="myselect1" input-field="newlass1">
    <option value="1">1</option>
    <option value="2">2</option>
    <option value="3">3</option>
    <option value="4">4</option>
</select>
<input class="returnValue newlass1" type="text" value=""><br>
<select id="myselect2" input-field="newlass2">
    <option value="1">1</option>
    <option value="2">2</option>
    <option value="3">3</option>
    <option value="4">4</option>
</select>
<input class="returnValue newlass2" type="text" value=""><br>
<select id="myselect3" input-field="newlass3">
    <option value="1">1</option>
    <option value="2">2</option>
    <option value="3">3</option>
    <option value="4">4</option>
</select>
<input class="returnValue newlass3" type="text" value=""><br>
<select id="myselect4" input-field="newlass4">
    <option value="1">1</option>
    <option value="2">2</option>
    <option value="3">3</option>
    <option value="4">4</option>
</select>
<input class="returnValue newlass4" type="text" value="">
```

Comment: Thank a lot for help. I use product id from database instead hard coded 1, 2, 3, 4 , Real magic is jQuery Thanks again.

Comment: @MirzaAdilAliBaig Thanks so much to you. I'm happy to see you glad.

Answer (score 1):

Use `$(this).parent().next('.returnValue').val($( this ).text());` to set value to the next input field.

```js
$(".myselect").change(function () {
   
    $( "select option:selected" ).each(function() {
        
        $(this).parent().next('.returnValue').val($( this ).text());
    });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<select class="myselect">
    <option value="1">1</option>
    <option value="2">2</option>
    <option value="3">3</option>
    <option value="4">4</option>
</select>

<input class="returnValue" type="text" value="">

<select class="myselect">
    <option value="1">1</option>
    <option value="2">2</option>
    <option value="3">3</option>
    <option value="4">4</option>
</select>

<input class="returnValue" type="text" value="">
<select class="myselect">
    <option value="1">1</option>
    <option value="2">2</option>
    <option value="3">3</option>
    <option value="4">4</option>
</select>

<input class="returnValue" type="text" value="">
```

Comment: First of all id should be unique in DOM. And that's why in your snippet value in input is get populated only when change first select.

Comment: @RahulPatel right, I know. I just copy pasted the same thing and forgot to that, sure. I will edit it to incorporate class.

Comment: @RahulPatel thanks for reminding. :) I should check once after posting atleast. my mistake.

Answer (score 0):

your problem is using the same class for all input fields, you need to set a different `id` for each input field

here's a [plunker](https://plnkr.co/edit/rK7ZEoVJ1ADWzRMVA9qk?p=preview)