# How to input one data and the other data is completed automatically?

Tags: javascript, php, mysql, database, laravel

I wonder how to apply one data and the other data is automatically completed to the code.

I've tried pluck() method and I just get value like the code bellow :

this is the controller

```
public function __construct(PKLRepository $pKLRepo)
{
    $this->pKLRepository = $pKLRepo;
    $this->data = Siswa::pluck('nis','id');
}

public function create()
{
    return view('p_k_l_s.create')
            ->with('data', $this->data);
}
```

create.blade.php

```
<div class="form-group col-sm-6">
{!! Form::label('nis', 'NIS:') !!}
{!! Form::select('nis', $data, null, ['class' => 'form-control']) !!}
</div>

<!-- Name Field -->
<div class="form-group col-sm-6">
    {!! Form::label('name', 'Nama:') !!}
    {!! Form::text('name', null,['class' => 'form-control']) !!}
</div>

<!-- Academic Year Field -->
<div class="form-group col-sm-12 col-lg-12">
    {!! Form::label('academic_year', 'Tahun Akademik:') !!}
    {!! Form::text('academic_year', null, ['class' => 'form-control']) 
     !!}
</div>
```

[image]

the code above just return nis value, but I want to autocompleted the form if I select one of the values from nis. Any suggest?

Comment: to complete this need apply `ajax` to pass value

Comment: Your question is too vague and unclear.

Comment: This requires understanding of Javascript instead of the all the tags you put. I just added the tag

Comment: Basically, what do you need to figure out are these:

 1. How to detect select dropdown changes?
 2. How to get current values of the input?
 3. How to call to the server to get other fields informations based on the selected value? 
 4. How to set other input value after the server return the result?

Comment: just like number 3 @geckob, so i need to use jquery right?

Comment: @tasyadas Yes you could but not necessarily. jQuery probably will make it easier

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39578546/how-to-populate-dynamic-input-field-with-dynamic-select-option-in-jquery